# Wildfly not allowing variable substitution in named-formatter

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly

With latest Wildfly (version 18.0.0.Final), if I attempt to put a variable substitution for the `named-formatter` like this (in `standalone.xml`):

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="${some.property:COLOR-PATTERN}"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
```

On start up, I get a FATAL error that looks like this:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE' are not available:
    org.wildfly.logging.formatter.${some.property:COLOR-PATTERN}; Possible registration points for this capability: 
        /subsystem=logging/pattern-formatter=*
        /subsystem=logging/custom-formatter=*
        /subsystem=logging/json-formatter=*
        /subsystem=logging/xml-formatter=*
        /subsystem=logging/logging-profile=*/pattern-formatter=*
        /subsystem=logging/logging-profile=*/custom-formatter=*
        /subsystem=logging/logging-profile=*/json-formatter=*
        /subsystem=logging/logging-profile=*/xml-formatter=*
```

I've filed a bug with jboss, but was wondering if anyone had run across this and had a good work-around.  I really need this to be configurable, ie I can't use a literal name for `named-formatter` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the [`named-formatter`](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/18.0/subsystem/logging/console-handler/index.html) attribute does not allow expressions. This was an intentional decision as boot time logging would not support this. See [WFCORE-157](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-157) for some reasons why.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This used to work for version 13 and ran into this when attempting to upgrade to latest (v18) version.   I think I have a work-around for this - I am making my custom formatter configurable so that I can pass this the variable properties instead of toggling to a specific formatter class.